# What is the ultimate date at which the Platform App Builder Transition exam can be taken?

Tags: certification, dev401, app-builder

DEV 401 is a dead end. Who knows how much time we have left for this transition to App Builder exam? It's not in the study guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received an email from Salesforce, stating, among other things: "transition exams are available until March 30, 2018"

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's the end of 2016